# drawing path with combination of color

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I have totally 5 locations latitude and longitude values and i want to draw aline on google map through those 5 locations in sequence with combination of colors. Is it possible? If possible how it can be done

Comment: Have you looked at the Google maps API? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

Answer (score 0):

**[Google Maps Directions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/) API**,  will help you a lot.

[image: map]

Here is a `Good Tutorial + Demo` for what you are looking:

**http://dreamdealer.nl/tutorials/getting_directions_with_google_maps.html**

You have to play with the code and you can achieve it with multiple colors.

Hope this helps.